# Are there Ethereum Level 2 Rollup scaling solutions that support ERC-1155?

Tags: scalability, zksnark, rollups, zksync

I've been doing my research on Level 2 Scaling solutions in general and docs are generally pretty lacking in detail. Usually, they just state general ideas and I'm looking for examples and concrete integration guides.

Basically, I'm looking for a Zk-rollup scaling solution that can process ERC-1155 transactions when the ERC-1155 itself would be deployed on Level 1. I've looked at StarkEx, Aztec 2.0, zkSync, and a couple of others but they either have little documentation on this or their allowed tokens list only includes some ERC-20 tokens.

Do you know about such a scaling solution? If yes, I would appreciate if you link me a website and docs, please.